# How to exclude whole word only in negative lookahead

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:

```
^(?!FIT|FAT|FUTURE)[F-I].*
```

`[F-I]` shows that any words starting with `F` to `I` should match apart from the given list of words that shouldn't match.

Currently, it doesn't match a word like `FITTER`, but I only want the regex to not match if it's a whole word such as `FIT`, `FAT` and `FUTURE`.

These are following scenarios I want it to work for:

**Matches**

```
FUTURE-YES
FITTER
GOOD
ITCHY
```

**Non Matches**

```
FIT
FAT
FUTURE
```

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what `[F-I]` is supposed to do? I'm not sure it's relation to the rest of the expression (other than the `F` being in there)

Comment: It is a range of words that start with F to I (so F, G, H, I). So words that start with G will match but not words starting with K or L and son

Comment: Ok was just making sure it wasn't an incorrect set.

Comment: `/^(?!FIT |FAT |FUTURE )[F-I].*/m`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Brief

Usually, you would use word boundaries `\b` to ensure the *edge* of a word. In your case, however, you have some words that use hyphens `-`, thus, this is likely the solution you're looking for.

---

### Code

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/fDay7a/2)

```
^(?!(?:FIT|FAT|FUTURE)(?![\w-]))[F-I][\w-]*$
```

---

### Results

#### Input

```
FUTURE-YES
FITTER
GOOD
ITCHY

FIT
FAT
FUTURE
```

#### Output

**Note**: Shown below are matches

```
FUTURE-YES
FITTER
GOOD
ITCHY
```

---

### Explanation

- `^` Assert position at the start of the line
- `(?!(?:FIT|FAT|FUTURE)(?![\w-]))` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows does not match

  - `(?:FIT|FAT|FUTURE)` Match either `FIT`, `FAT` or `FUTURE` literally
  - `(?![\w-])` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows does not match a word character or hyphen `-`
- `[F-I]` Match a character between `F` and `I` (`FGHI`)
- `[\w-]*` Match any word character or hyphen `-` character any number of times
- `$` Assert position at the end of the line